# How to run Django project using travisCI

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a Django project that I'm building using TravisCI which is supposed to be running the test class I have. For some reason, when the build runs, it succeeds, but the output of the job says that 0 tests were run:

[image]

I was originally using the command `python manage.py test` to run the build, but for some reason, it didn't seem to be working so I then ran the command `python src/manage.py test FileUploadTestClass.test_uploaded_file` but this results in an import error for the test class.

**What is the proper way to run the django testing framework using TravisCI?**

**.travis.yml**

```
language: python
python:
- "2.7"
# setup environment
env:
- DJANGO_VERSION=1.11.2
- DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='di_photouploader.settings.production'
# install dependencies
install:
- pip install -r requirements.txt

# run test scripts
script:
- python src/manage.py test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of issues. First, you apparently aren't able to run the test from the parent directory so before `python src/manage.py test` is run, you would have to change into the directory where manage.py is located. Also,`unittest.TestCase` needed to be passed into the class definition instead of `django.test.TestCase`.

Comment: How can I change for the directory where manage.py is located?